# x[row].length, don't understand

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, 2d

I have recently been relearning java after 2 years of not coding in it, and I have forgotten why we put `x[row].length` in these lines 13-17:

```
public class apples {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int firstarray[][]={{8,9,10,11},{12,13,14,15}};
        int secondarray[][]={{30,31,32,33},{43},{4,5,6}};
        
        System.out.println("This is the first array");
        display(firstarray);
        
        System.out.println("This is the second array");
        display(secondarray);
    }

    public static void display(int x[][]){
        for(int row=0;row<x.length;row++){
            for(int column=0;column<x[row].length;column++){
                System.out.print(x[row][column]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a 2-D array, that line is simply getting the size of that particular dimension of the array so that no out-of-bounds exceptions occur. In this case, it is telling you (or the loop) how many cells are in each column of the 2-D array.

Answer (score 0):

`x[row].length` will get the length of the array in the row numbered "row" because `x` is an array of `int` arrays. The nested for loops go through each index in the 2D array, and then through each element of the array at index `row`.

Answer (score 0):

Its because, 2-D Array is really an **Array of Arrays**

```
x[row][col]  -->  represents a single integer in that array
x[row]       -->  represents a 1D array (a single row in the 2D array)
```